# Sets vs. Regex for string lookup, which is more scalable?

Tags: python, regex, data-structures, set

Suppose that I need to handle a very big list of words, and I need to count the number of times I find any of those words in a piece of text I have.
Which is the best option in terms of scalability?

Option I (regex)

```
>>> import re
>>> s = re.compile("|".join(big_list))
>>> len(s.find_all(sentence))
```

Option II (sets)

```
>>> s = set(big_list)
>>> len([word for word in sentence.split(" ") if word in s]) # O(1) avg lookup time
```

Example: if the list is ["cat","dog","knee"] and the text is "the dog jumped over the cat, but the dog broke his knee" the final result should be: 4

P.S. Any other option is welcome

Comment: Note that your two options will return different results even on your test data.  (the `set` option won't pick up `'cat,'` whereas the regex will).

Comment: [Aho–Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) is fast and clever, but I don't know of a Python implementation.

Comment: @msw: There's a link to one at the bottom of the article: http://papercruncher.com/2012/02/26/string-searching-using-aho-corasick/

Comment: I might use the `set` version but iterate over `re.finditer(r'\b\w+\b',sentence)` (but this is dependent on your list of words being alphanumeric).  And I might use the old standby `sum( 1 for x in ... if ... )` rather than using `len`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your words are alphanumeric, I might use something like:

```
s = set(big_list)
sum(1 for x in re.finditer(r'\b\w+\b',sentence) if x.group() in s)
```

Since the membership test for a set is on average O(1), this algorithm becomes O(N+M) where N is the number of words in the sentence and M is the number of elements in big_list.  Not too shabby.  It also does pretty well in terms of memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

A scalable method would be sorting the input dictionary and words from the text then doing the matching using two iterators. You can also [use a trie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11016430/390913) for even better performance. I don't know the internal representation of the set, however, using a large regex would be a total overkill.