# Python - Check if string is the start of an English word

Tags: python, spell-checking, pyenchant

I've been playing around with various modules (e.g. PyEnchant), and what I want to do is determine if a string is the beginning of an English word. E.g.

```
Smo -> Smoke
A x -> x-ray 
Elx -> NULL
Don -> Done
Brj -> NULL
Bes -> Besiege
Nix -> Nixed
```

But I'm unsure if there is a way to do it, without creating and loading my own word list.

Comment: It doesn't look like PyEnchant supports this, but there are many ways of doing it. But yes, you'll need a word list to compare against.

Comment: It is pretty easy to implement,  getting a complete wordlist would be about the hardest part

Answer (score 3):

Python does not ship with it's own word list, so you would have to load it from somewhere (whether it's a common dictionary, a custom list, etc.).

Now I'm not sure about PyEnchant, but the easiest way to then do this is to create a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) structure within Python as then checking if a word exists is as easy as going through graph nodes till either you hit a null (return False for word existing with that prefix) or you hit the last character in your search string (return True for word existing with that prefix.) A sample on making a Trie can be found in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015320/how-to-create-a-trie-in-python).