# Python Trie implementation why create temporary variable

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, implementation, trie

I looked at this code:

```
>>> _end = '_end_'
>>> 
>>> def make_trie(*words):
...     root = dict()
...     for word in words:
...         current_dict = root
...         for letter in word:
...             current_dict = current_dict.setdefault(letter, {})
...         current_dict = current_dict.setdefault(_end, _end)
...     return root
... 
>>> make_trie('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'barz')
{'b': {'a': {'r': {'_end_': '_end_', 'z': {'_end_': '_end_'}}, 
         'z': {'_end_': '_end_'}}}, 
'f': {'o': {'o': {'_end_': '_end_'}}}}
```

from this link: [How to create a TRIE in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015320/how-to-create-a-trie-in-python/11016430?noredirect=1#), but I don't quite understand why does the author create the temporary variable current_dict since you are always just editing the dictionary called root...

Comment: I deleted my totally wrong thought about how the code works, sorry!   I still do think this question belongs at codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Should I ask questions about implementations there in the future? if so, why?

Comment: StackOverflow is for specific questions about a specific problem with code (read [help] for more details).  CodeReview is for soliciting input about how code can be improved and the rationale for doing things in certain ways.

Comment: I see, thanks!  I just added my next question on unionfind to codereview here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/91070/union-find-why-use-value-not-idp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't quite understand why does the author create the temporary variable current_dict since you are always just editing the dictionary called root...

No, you're not. If it was always editing the root dictionary, the result would be very different. Every time the assignment inside the loop is executed:

```
...         current_dict = root
...         for letter in word:
...             current_dict = current_dict.setdefault(letter, {}) # this one
```

`current_dict` is set to a dictionary one level further in. This loop traverses the trie, using `setdefault` to build missing parts as needed. We have to assign the `setdefault` result to `current_dict` to keep going down the trie instead of staying at top level, and we have to use a separate `current_dict` variable instead of `root` so we can assign `current_dict = root` to get back to top level once we're done with a word.

Comment: why is it that `current_dict` is set to a dictionary one level further in? I don't see how that happened.

Comment: @KevinZhao: Do you know what `setdefault` returns?

Comment: According to TutorialsPoint(http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_setdefault.htm), "This method returns the key value available in the dictionary and if given key is not available then it will return provided default value." so basically the current_dict will equal to a new dictionary after the first time, then when I run the setdefault line again, I am setting the new dictionary's key and values, which is one level in, is that right?

Comment: @KevinZhao: Correct.