# Get a string with highest amount of prefixes

Tags: python, string, performance, python-3.x, prefix

I have a list of strings, for example:

```
py
python
co
comp
computer
```

I simply want to get a string, which contains the biggest possible amount of prefixes. The result should be 'computer' because its prefixes are 'co' and 'comp' (2 prefixes).

I have this code (wordlist is a dictionary):

```
for i in wordlist:
    word = str(i)
    for j in wordlist:
        if word.startswith(j):
            wordlist[i] += 1
result = max(wordlist, key=wordlist.get)
```

Is there any better, faster way to do that?

Comment: Well one improvement would be to cut the `word = str(i)` part out and simply the variable `i`. If `i` is already a string, there is no reason to convert it. Unless I'm missing something very obvious...

Comment: You might be able to use a radix tree, but I think that would still be O(n^2)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Why would it be O(n**2)? You could simply iterate over all the leaves and count the terminal nodes between leaf and root node.

Comment: @EricDuminil You'd have to build the tree as well.  I think that's worst-case n**2

Comment: @PatrickHaugh It's O(m*n) with n the number of words and m the average word length. In the above case, `m` is probably bounded, so it's O(n)

Answer (score 1):

The data structure you are looking for is called a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). The Wikipedia article about this kind of search tree is certainly worth reading. The key property of the trie that comes in handy here is this:

> All the descendants of a node have a common prefix of the string associated with that node, and the root is associated with the empty string.

The code could look as follows:

```
words = """py
python
co
comp
computer""".split()

def make_trie(ws):
    """Build trie from word list `ws`."""
    r = {}  # trie root
    for w in ws:
        d = r
        for c in w:
            d = d.setdefault(c, {})  # get c, set to {} if missing
        d['$'] = '$' # end marker
    return r

def num_pref(t, ws):
    """Use trie `t` to find word with max num of prefixes in `ws`."""
    b, m = -1, ''  # max prefixes, corresp. word
    for w in ws:
        d, p = t, 1
        for c in w:
            if '$' in d: p += 1
            d = d[c]  # navigate down one level
        if p > b: b, m = p, w
    return b, m

t = make_trie(words)
print(num_pref(t, words))
```

`make_trie` builds the trie, `num_pref` uses it to determine the word with maximum number of prefixes. It prints `(3, 'computer')`.

Obviously, the two methods could be combined. I kept them separate to make the process of building a trie more clear.

Comment: `make_trie` is impressively compact. UPDATE: It's also the exact same code as the link from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For a large amount of words, you could build a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

You could then iterate over all the leaves and count the amount of nodes (terminal nodes) with a value between the root and the leaf.

With n words, this should require `O(n)` steps compared to your `O(n**2)` solution.

This [package](https://github.com/google/pygtrie) looks good, and here's a related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015320/how-to-create-a-trie-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

The "correct" way is with some sort of trie data structure or similar. However, if your words are already sorted you can get quite a speedup in practical terms with some rather simple code that uses a prefix stack instead of a brute force search. This works since in sorted order, all prefixes precede their prefixed word (making it easy to get a result via a simple linear scan). Think of it as a reasonable compromise between simple code and efficient code:

```
prefixes = []   # Stack of all applicable prefixes up to this point (normally very small)
max_prefixes = [None]
for w in sorted(wordlist):
    while prefixes and not w.startswith(prefixes[-1]):
        prefixes.pop()
    prefixes.append(w)
    if len(prefixes) >= len(max_prefixes):
        max_prefixes = list(prefixes)
result = max_prefixes[-1]
```

Running on all dictionary words on my Linux box (479828 of them), the above code takes only 0.68s seconds (the original code doesn't complete in a reasonable amount of time). On the first 10000 words, my code takes **0.02s instead of 19.5s** taken by the original code.

If you want *really* efficient code (say, you're dealing with gigabytes of data), you're better off using the proper data structures coded up in a cache-friendly manner in C. But that could take weeks to write properly!