# Can someone explain def _trie(): return defaultdict(_trie)

Tags: python, trie, defaultdict

Can someone explain `def _trie(): return defaultdict(_trie)` ?

I know `defaultdict` and it looks like a recursive function. But I have not figured out how function name can become a parameter to defaultdict.

BTW, I got this [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) implementation from https://stackoverflow.com/a/49357789/301513

Comment: This is the way to get a default dict to have a default dict as the default value, which itself has default dict as its value and so on recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument for `defaultdict` *is* a function.

Start by calling `_trie`:

```
>>> d = _trie()
>>> d
defaultdict(<function _trie at 0x105a9e400>, {})
```

You now have an instance of `defaultdict`. What happens if you try to access a non-existent key?

```
>>> d[3]
defaultdict(<function _trie at 0x105a9e400>, {})
```

You get back *another* `defaultdict`, because `d[3]` is short for `d.__getitem__(3)` invokes `d.__missing__(3)`, which calls `d.__setattr__(d, 3, _trie()`.

It reflects the recursive definition of a trie: a trie is either empty or a single node with tries as children. This creates a `defaultdict` that is either empty, or has arbitrary keys mapped to other `defaultdict`s with the same factory function.

It's a little bit like mutual recursion. A call to `_trie` results in a call to `defaultdict`, but a call to `defaultdict.__getitem__` or `defaultdict.__setitem__` (rather than a call to `defaultdict` itself) results in a call to `_trie`.