# python assign by reference in default dict

Tags: python-3.x, trie, defaultdict

In python implementation of `trie` with `defaultdict`, it is suspicious how this works?

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def trie():
    return defaultdict(trie)
```

Creating Trie:

```py
node = trie()

node
# defaultdict(<function __main__.trie()>, {})

node[0]
# defaultdict(<function __main__.trie()>, {})

node == node[0]
# False

node
# defaultdict(<function __main__.trie()>,
#            {0: defaultdict(<function __main__.trie()>, {})})
```

Can anyone explain how did `key=0` got added into trie `node`?

Comment: Complete `trie` implementation can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49357789/11539544

Comment: "how did key=0" ... have you read the documentation for `defaultdict`?? If you try to access a key that doesn't exist, it runs the factory function and assigns it to that key, so when you did `node[0]`

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga. Apologies for silly question.
I was confused if self referencing function as `default_factory` had anything to do with it. But it was standard behavior of `defaultdict`.
Now I truly understood the implementation of `trie` as `defaultdict` with `default_factory` as self referencing function, instead of simple dict. This is because of **lazy** evaluation.