# Update a deeply nested dictionary with a given pathway

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I use Python 3.9 and I have a deeply nested dictionary with integers in it. I have a pathway (a key list) that specifies which value in the dictionary I want to modify (increase by one). If the pathway doesn'r exist, I want to create them.

For example:

```
keyList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] #this is the pathway
```

and I want to modify (update) the following dictionary

```
myDict = {}

def modFun(pKeyList:list):
    global myDict
    #some code that modifies the directory

modFun(keyList)
print(myDict)

#it returns {'a' : {'b' : {'c' : {'d' : 1}}}}

keyList = ['a', 'c']
modFun(keyList)
print(myDict)

#it returns {'a' : {'c' : 1, 'b' : {'c' : {'d' : 1}}}}

keyList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
modFun(keyList)
print(myDict)

#it returns {'a' : {'c' : 1, 'b' : {'c' : {'d' : 2}}}}
```

Comment: It would be an interesting challenge to write this question in a more obscure and puzzling manner. Suggestion: try to rephrase it.

Comment: And do you really, really want deeply nested dict?

Comment: buran: Yes, is there any way to do this?

Comment: bbbbbbbbb: I tried to rephrase it, now?

Comment: It appears that you want a `dict` subclass that's a mix of nesting dictionaries but acts like a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) as well. What should happen after the last line if you 'add a keylist' of [a,b,c,d,e]?

Comment: @kcsquared counter is like a dictionary, no? So, how can I create a deeply nested counter or dictionary?

Comment: This seems very, very similar to a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), where your terminal nodes contain a frequency count. It's possible that a [standalone Trie class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015320/how-to-create-a-trie-in-python) fits your use case, if you want to search for keylists or prefixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could use `dict.setdefault` iteratively:

```
def update_myDict(myDict):
    d = myDict
    for k in keyList:
        if k == keyList[-1]:
            d[k] = d.get(k, 0) + 1
        else:
            d = d.setdefault(k, {})
    return myDict
```

Output:

```
>>> update_myDict({})
{'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 1}}}}

>>> update_myDict({'a' : {'c' : 1}})
{'a': {'c': 1, 'b': {'c': {'d': 1}}}}

>>> update_myDict({'a' : {'c' : 1, 'b' : {'c' : {'d' : 1}}}}) 
{'a': {'c': 1, 'b': {'c': {'d': 2}}}}
```