# Python Dictionary Search is taking long time

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, dictionary, data-structures

I am writing a lambda in python where I am searching elements within dictionary without exact match.

```
for security_data_item in security_list_per_prefix_raw_m:
    investment_vehicle_id = security_data_item.get_investment_vehicle_id()
    unique_id = investment_vehicle_id


    ext_security_dict_keys = list(dict(filter(lambda item: item[0].startswith(unique_id), 
    security_dict.items())).keys())
```

When I am running this my lambda is getting time-out. security_dict will have too many items. I can not use exact match `security_dict.get(unique_id)` Is there any better way I can search?
I also tried this `ext_security_dict_keys = [val for key, val in security_dict.items() if re.search(unique_id, key)]`

Comment: Partial search defeats the purpose of using a hashed data type such as a dictionary. Approximately how many items will there be? What is the maximum length of a key? What is the minimum length of a `unique_id` you want to partially search for? Where does `security_dict` come from? Can you use another data type instead of a dict?

Comment: "I can not use exact match" then you have no choice but to iterate through the dictionary and check one-by-one.

Comment: Use a different data structure, [such as a trie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015320). To the extent that this question is distinct and answerable, I don't think it's really a Python-specific question, but a general data structures and algorithms question.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Of course they have other choices. They could use a trie, as Karl Knechtel mentioned, or even generate additional lookup keys in the same dict, even though it is not ideal.

Comment: Not sure how I can use trie in this case?

Comment: You are comparing the beginning of the keys in the `security_dict` with the `unique_id`. Does this mean that every key in `security_dict` is of the form `unique_id-something`? If so, can you pre-convert the dictionary to have `unique_id` as a key, like `dict[unique_id, list[item]]`?

Comment: @user3420305 You should clarify your question by answering the questions above, first.

Comment: @Ken unique_id  in security_dict  might be 'F000000EU6XNAS' however my list would have value = 'F000000EU6' which I wanted to search in security_dict  without exact match.  I did not get this part - ``` dict[unique_id, list[item]]```

Comment: @Selcuk I meant "no other choice if you continue to use a dictionary mapping those keys to those values", of course, you can use a different data structure or approach.

Comment: @user3420305  do you know in advance what the length of the overlap will be?

Answer (score 0):

You're going through too many data structure iteration/creation.  You can get the result directly from iterating on the dictionary (it iterates on its keys)

```
*ext_security_dict_keys, = filter(lambda k:k.startswith(unique_id),security_dict)
```

or

```
ext_security_dict_keys = [k for k in security_dict if k.startswith(unique_id)]
```